Read logs stored in new relic
We currently are looking to build a UI and query capabilities to search the logs exported to New Relic. The user would search for a string in our application and we would build the query and retrieve the results. The .net sdk from new relic was able to export the logs
We have done same with Splunk in past using the SDK for C# (SearchOneShotAsync) and it has worked without any issues.
